# What is the water content of avian blood?

Tags: zoology, physiology, hematology

I'm doing a work about heavy metal contamination in seabirds. I have found that the toxic threshold for Cu in blood is 1,15 μg/g wet weight. That number refers to an average between some seabirds. I need to convert that value from wet weight to dry weight.

Comment: You're going to have to be a good deal more specific than that.  "What percent water" - does that include the water inside erythrocytes & WBCs?  And what species?  Some birds increase their hematocrit in preparation for migration, which could throw levels off; some birds live in the desert wheras others live in the water, which could effect normal "percentage of water."  Please [edit] your question to specify what research you have done so far and what information specifically you are after.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ifer May i ask you why do you even want to know this information?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in the blog and I don't know how it works yet, but thank you for the advice :)